# How to keep a running total column but stop by condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to fulfill some quantity for a few products.
Say I have 100 records for product Foo and each record has a quantity of between 1-100.
I just got an order for 25 quantity of Foo.

I can of course pull all records back and just take what I need but I would like to figure out how to return just enough records to fulfill the request.

I believe I'm pretty close here but not able to figure out how to limit the records coming back once I've hit my goal.

```
declare @neededQty = 10

;WITH Products as 
(
Select 
    p.Name, 
    sp.Price,
    sp.Quantity,
    SUM(sp.Quantity)OVER(PARTITION BY p.Name order by sp.Price, sp.Quantity desc) as QtyRunningTotal
from Product p
    inner join ProductDetails sp on sp.ProductId = p.ProductId
where productId IN (1,2,3,4)
)
select 
* from Products
where QtyRunningTotal >= @neededQty
```

This is the current output but I would like it to return only the 1st Foo record since I only need 10 quantity

```
Name    Price   Quantity    QtyRunningTotal
--------------------------------------------
Foo     1       15          15
Foo     1       15          30
Foo     1       15          45
Foo     1       15          60
Foo     1       100         160
Foo     1       100         260
Foo     1       100         360
Bar     1       10          10
Bar     1       10          20
Bar     1       10          30
```

Comment: Can you just take just Top 1 recordS?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle ,MS SQLServer etc.,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this predicate.

```
where Name = 'Foo' 
      and QtyRunningTotal - Quantity < @neededQty
```

Comment: One last use case I didn't realize maybe you could help with. Not sure if I should create a new post or not but I don't want any rows returned if the quantity couldn't be fulfilled.

Comment: Then you also need an additional column for total `SUM(sp.Quantity)OVER(PARTITION BY p.Name) as QtyTotal` and filter for `QtyTotal > @neededQty`

Comment: Perfect, ty again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where the running total has more quantity that you want. Try this:

```
;WITH Products as 
(
Select 
    p.Name, 
    sp.Price,
    sp.Quantity,
    SUM(sp.Quantity)OVER(PARTITION BY p.Name order by sp.Price, sp.Quantity desc) as QtyRunningTotal
from Product p
    inner join ProductDetails sp on sp.ProductId = p.ProductId
where productId IN (1,2,3,4)
)
select 
* from Products
where neededQty >= ABS(neededQty - QtyRunningTotal)
```

```
Name    Price   Quantity    QtyRunningTotal   Required  total-req 
------------------------------------------------------------------
Foo     1       15          15                10        -5        
Foo     1       15          30                10        -20        
Foo     1       15          45                10        -35        
Foo     1       15          60                10        -50        
Foo     1       100         160               10        -150        
Foo     1       100         260               10        -250        
Foo     1       100         360               10        -350        
Bar     1       10          10                10        0        
Bar     1       10          20                10        -10        
Bar     1       10          30                10        -20
```

Answer (score 0):

I calculated that you would need a range given your data set.  I also assumed that you wanted to pull back the least amount of product as possible first i.e. if I only needed 15 items I would pull back the records with say 10 and 11 and not the one record with 100.  Here is an option:

```
CREATE TABLE #Product(ProductID int, ProdName varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE #ProductDetails(ProductID int, Price int, Quantity int)

INSERT INTO #Product(ProductID, ProdName) VALUES(1, 'FOO')
INSERT INTO #Product(ProductID, ProdName) VALUES(2, 'BAR')

INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,15)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,16)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,17)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,18)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,100)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,101)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(1,1,102)

INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(2,1,10)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(2,1,11)
INSERT INTO #ProductDetails(ProductID,Price,Quantity) VALUES(2,1,12)

declare @neededQty int = 32

;WITH Products as 
(
Select 
    p.ProdName, 
    sp.Price,
    sp.Quantity,
     LAG(sp.Quantity,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY p.ProdName order by sp.Price, sp.Quantity  ) LG
from #Product p
    inner join #ProductDetails sp on sp.ProductId = p.ProductId
where p.productId IN (1,2,3,4)
), Prod2 AS
(
select * , 
SUM(LG) OVER(PARTITION BY ProdName ORDER BY Price, LG ) LowRange
,SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ProdName ORDER BY Price, Quantity ) HighRange
from Products)

SELECT * 
FROM Prod2
WHERE LowRange < @neededQty OR  @neededQty >= HighRange
```